# Button in DataGridView with condition C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors, conditional-statements

I want to ADD button to a column in DataGridView...But with a condtion :  just when the color of the ROW is RED, 
This is datagridview:

[image]

Now, all the button in Column 'Check-Out' work...with the Red Row or the White Row...my code:

```
int row = (int)this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningRow.Cells[0].Value;

            if (MessageBox.Show("Check-out?",
                              "Message de confirmation",
                              MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {    MessageBox.Show("Success!!");
}
```

For just the button work with Red ROW,
I try this code :

```
 if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Red)
        {
            int row = (int)this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningRow.Cells[0].Value;

            if (MessageBox.Show("Check-out?",
                              "Message de confirmation",
                              MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {MessageBox.Show("Success!!");
}
```

I have ERROR: The index was off limits. It must not be negative and must be less than the size of the collection. in line:

```
 if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Red)
```

ERROR:

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the correct answer: I should modifie the line :

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.Red)
```

with :

```
 if(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor==Color.Red)
```

So we use  DataGridView.CurrentRow